# Recovering Whatsapp messages after IPhone crashed

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, crash, whatsapp.app

The following happened, I would be so grateful if you helped me:

- April 29: Whatsapp last backup
- May 6 evening: IPhone ICloud last backup
- I don’t open Whatsapp for a whole day and most of my conversations are muted
- May 7: IPhone crashes, nothing to do about it
- May 8: I get a new IPhone, ICloud restores everything
- I have messages from my family while the old phone was crashed. I also have texts from April 30, May 1st etc. so after the Whatsapp last backup
- I have no texts between May 6 evening and May 7. So between the IPhone last backup and the crash. There is just one person who could have written me, but they were muted and I never opened. Is it possible that I lost/missed their (possible) message?

Comment: iCloud would have restored all your old WhatsApp messages from the WhatsApp backup made on April 29. Any other messages you are seeing after April 29 must have been restored from the WhatsApp server - WhatsApp keeps **undelivered** messages on their server for around 30 days. After a message is delivered, WhatsApp claims it deletes it from their server. So unless you have a backup of your chats (which you don't from April 29), it is not possible to recover all the delivered WhatsApp messages sent between April 29 to May 8.

Comment: @sfxedit Thank you for the info! But I am however able to see messages after April 29 - they were delivered and open and read at the time. An IPhone backup (not Whatsapp) took place on May 6 evening, and my phone crashed on May 7 evening. The problem is exactly this timeslot - I didn’t check Whatsapp and the notifications were turned off, and I wonder if I could have gotten any message that was lost when I switched phones.